# javascript form calculation returns NaN

Tags: javascript, checkbox, textbox, radio-button

I have an order form and a JavaScript which should calculate grand total from textbox (quantity*price), checkbox and radio, but I'm missing something because i receive a NaN error. Could somebody help me fix it?
Thanks a lot.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/asosos/21/edit)

Comment: You should start by reading & fixing the 5 warnings that JS Bin shows.

Comment: whole concept is flawed starting your calculation variable out as a string then concatenation other strings to it...and expecting a number in return. Use console to log values will see it;s a real mess

Comment: You should not try to fix this mess but rewrite it from scratch, without using `eval`. Because right now you are literally executing the users input (form field values) as javascript code! And you are just one step (accepting url parameters) away from trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many have commented, there are some serious short-comings to your code. I won't re-iterate these concerns, however, they are very important and you should learn as you are getting more acquainted with the technologies you are using.

The reason you are getting a **NaN** is this. Your fields object is an array. Your code populates the fields array at an arbitrary indices, i.e. **fields[f] = 0**;

When you populate the array for index, say 5, your code does this **fields[5] = 0**;. With this statement you went from having an empty array **[]**, to having an array with 6 entries with the first 5 entries being defaulted to undefined **[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 0]**.

Now later in your code when you do the summation and add the arrays entries up (using eval having prepared a string) these **...undefined+0+undefined+8...** are producing a Not A Number error.

Instead, one way to prevent this is to **push** entries onto the fields array like:

```
if (userInputs[f].value)
{
  fields.push(userInputs[f].value);
}
else
{
  fields.push(0);
}
```

push will add one entry to the end of the array. **[]** will become **[0]** if you **push(0)**.

Comment: thank you all for suggestions, i thought that i was close to solve this form but apparently i'm not. the only solution that i see at this point is to dig deeper into learning JavaScript.